# Getting possible combinations of a set of "STRINGS" - PYTHON

Tags: python, string, combinations, python-itertools

For getting possible combinations of set of "**characters**", syntax would be:

```
>>>q=[''.join(p) for p in itertools.combinations('ABC',2)]
>>>q
['AB', 'AC', 'BC']
```

What about getting possible combinations of set of "**STRINGS**"
for example :

> 'A1X2','B1','C19'

output should be:
    `['A1X2B1', 'A1X2C19', 'B1C19']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass `strings` instead. Instead of iterating on each char of `"ABC"`, `combinations` iterates on the strings contained in the `strings` list. And `join` acts the same (there is no difference between a character and a string in python, characters are just strings of size 1)

```
strings = ['A1X2','B1','C19']

q=[''.join(p) for p in itertools.combinations(strings,2)]
```

result:

```
['A1X2B1', 'A1X2C19', 'B1C19']
```