# Adding up the pieces and getting a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I’m hoping to combine a couple component python parts I have found on stack overflow with the end goal of automatically generating valid words and their definitions into a CSV file.

1) Please accept my apology if the answer to my question is simple and ‘right there!’ My one and only coding class was a multidisciplinary python course years ago.

2) I start with a list of letters (the actual letters and number in this set vary) and a word length. Once we have all the possible combinations, these combinations need to be run against a dictionary. Those which return as a word need to be placed in a CSV spreadsheet alongside their definition.

Getting Possible Combinations of a set of ‘STRINGS’ ([Getting possible combinations of a set of "STRINGS" - PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040123/getting-possible-combinations-of-a-set-of-strings-python)) would generate a library with the possible combinations.

And

Python define a word? ([Python define a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386514/python-define-a-word)) Would at least tell me if a letter combination is a word.

Due to my lack of experience, putting these elements together and finding a way to generate both the definitions and the spreadsheet seem beyond me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This script should do the job if I understand well.
In this example, "dico.txt" is a text file where each line is a word from the french dictionary (of course it works with other languages).

```py
from itertools import permutations

LETTERS = ["a", "b", "e", "t", "u"] # set it as you want
WORD_LENGTH = 2                     # set it as you want

with open("dico.txt") as f:
    fr_words = f.read().split("\n") # french words

# all possible words
words = ["".join(c) for c in permutations(LETTERS, WORD_LENGTH)]

# french words among all possible words
print (*(w for w in words if w in fr_words), sep="\n")
```

Comment: Paul - 1st thank you! 2nd, the above solution would return all words within the given criteria according to those in the .txt document. Do you happen to know how to get the definition to also print? 

My original idea was to use some sort of URL address to gather the definitions from. Perhaps something like this? https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386514/python-define-a-word I also found an open source dictionary set which might also be useful https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/ instead. 

Again all ideas are helpful - thank you!